# How can I run a web app which is built using Angular and django on a single development server?

Tags: javascript, python, django, angular, server

I have a web application the front end is separated from the api, the front end is made of Angular running on a different development server (for example ***192.168.0.185:8000***). And my api which is built using Django runs on different development server (for example ***192.168.0.185:8080***). I am actually using 2 tabs (terminals) to run them.

My question: is there a way I can merge them so that I will only be using a single development server for the two of them? Would that affect my current project structure? Any idea? I know this is not about coding syntax or algorithms, hope you understand. Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked Server fault [here](https://serverfault.com/)? Have you tried to combine scripts, if so post them in the question by pasting and update.